# Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list (I'm new to this sorry)

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<html>
<canvas id="gameCanvas" width="800" height="600"></canvas>

<script>
var canvas;
var canvasContext;

window.onload = function() {
                   console.log("Hello World!");
                   canvas = document.getElementById('gameCanvas');
       canvasContext - canvas.getcontect('2d');
       canvasContext.fillSyle = 'black';
       canvasContext.fillRect(0,0 canvas.width,canvas.height);
       canvasContext.fillSyle = 'red';
       canvasContext.fillRect(100,200,50,25);
       
 }


</script>
<html>
```

Ok so I literally just started to learn how to code yesterday, but here's my problem. I know this question gets asked a lot but all i'm trying is to make a black rectangle in a google chrome html but it gives me this error. I have no idea why (I think I checked the other questions well enough(probably not)) but it wont  make a black rectangle. Now as I said I just started to code yesterday so I'm sorry if I wasted someone's time but i'm trying to make a pong-type game and I can't even make a canvas so could someone please explain to me as simple as possible why this wont work. And by the way when I did read the answers to the other similar questions I couldn't make any sense of them.

Comment: You need to edit your question and provide the code in question and in particular indicate the code where your error message is indicating it is happening.

Comment: Add a bit of your code it 'll make others to explain you what's wrong.

Comment: sorry I did but I went back to change something and I must of deleted it

Comment: `0,0 canvas.width` - missing something?

Comment: ...Line number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed [mistakes and typographical errors](https://www.diffchecker.com/W2vDAIYk).
[image]

```html
<html>
<canvas id="gameCanvas" width="800" height="600"></canvas>

<script>
  var canvas;
  var canvasContext;

  window.onload = function() {
    console.log("Hello World!");
    canvas = document.getElementById('gameCanvas');
    canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvasContext.fillStyle = 'black';
    canvasContext.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    canvasContext.fillStyle = 'red';
    canvasContext.fillRect(100, 200, 50, 25);

  }
</script>
<html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I will remember/use this as a reference so I don't misplace my commas and I wont make the same mistake again!

Comment: @Will you should install an IDE for JavaScript with code completion.

Comment: Couldn't you mention in your answer what you've fixed? There aren't that many differences, and we shouldn't need to go to an external resource to see them.

Comment: @nnnnnn I have added a screenshot.

Comment: As i said, I'm new to this but I really do appreciate you guys taking the time to answer my question. I will try to look further into the problem next time before I ask another question. Thanks!